# problem with using statement in gnuplot

Tags: using, gnuplot

I'm trying to plot some data. I have a file looking like this

```
50      11      1       1
100     29      1       6
200     62      4       26
300     104     9       39
```

and a plotfile

```
# Vergleich 
set terminal png
set output "streetsegments.png"
set datafile separator "\t"
set yrange [0:105]
set ytics ("0" 0, "10" 10, "20" 20, "30" 30, "40" 40, "50" 50, "75" 75, "100" 100)
set xtics ("50" 50, "100" 100, "200" 200,"300" 300)
set xrange [0:300]
set xlabel "Error in meters"    
set ylabel "Street segments"
set notitle
plot "segments" using 1:2 t 'foo' with lp, \
"segments" u 1:3 t 'bar' with lp, \
"segments" u 1:4 t 'baz' with lp
```

But when plotting, it doesn't show anything besides the titles of the lines, but no lines themselves are drawn. Any idea, why this doesn't work? 
When only plotting on column (by not using the "using"-statement ) it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. Try again removing the `set datafile separator "\t"` line and see if that solves it.